# vim-latex suite, how to open a file without folding the text by default

Tags: vim, latex, latex-suite

I have downloaded and successfully installed the *Vim-LaTeX Suite* from 
http://vim-latex.sf.net.

It is a great tool, but slightly annoying that when you open a file it folds all of the text and puts the folds in a collapsed state, as this page of the manual states:

http://vim-latex.sf.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-folding.html

So you have to type `zR` to expand everything each time you open a LaTeX file.

Typing `zR` is obviously not hugely annoying, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to disable this functionality, so that the file is displayed with the folds uncollapsed by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
setlocal foldlevel=999
```

This way, folding is kept intact, and all folds are only opened for Latex files. You can close all folds with `zM`.

<sub>(This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`.) Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType <filetype> setlocal` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set nofoldenable
```

Comment: That's too coarse; it will disable folding for _all_ files and filetypes.

Comment: Well, he was looking for "an easy way to disable this functionality" and that's what he got.

Comment: Yeah, difficult issue. both answers work, but the other one is a more precise answer to the question, which for better or worse is about this particular plugin. However, many people will want this behaviour in general, and so I believe it will still be a very useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

or set `foldlevel` to a higher value, e.g. `999`

actually, the zM, zR was setting this option too.